# What is special about this number?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

The number is 154967328. No other information is given, except that it's possible to answer in a minute (so no complex calculations). What is specil about the number?

Answer (score 3):

It has the digits 1 through 9 exactly, and the digits that perfect squares can end in (14569) come before the others.

Answer (score 2):

It contains all digits from 1 to 9.